# How to differentiate 2 IDs with simmilar letters

Tags: mysql

```
INSERT INTO `tablecity` (`City`, `Country`) VALUES ('Itajaí','Brazil');
INSERT INTO `tablecity` (`City`, `Country`) VALUES ('itajai','Brazil');
```

Yea I know the 2 must be the same city. Let's for a while pretend that those are 2 completely different cities.

Why do I get duplicate entries? The letters are different. How do I make mysql to treat the 2 entries differently?

Comment: Please show the table definition. What is the encoding/collation of the table and the fields?

Comment: What is the character set and the collation for the City column?

Comment: You should also show the code you're using to query the database.

Comment: show result of `desc tableName`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost certainly using a character set and/or collation which doesn't support the letter differences you're trying to insert here.

Something like this won't work and will result to the problem you're encountering:

```
CREATE TABLE `yourtable` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `city` varchar(28),
  `country` varchar(28),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `city` (`city`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin;
```

You won't go wrong using `utf8` / [`utf8_bin`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-binary-collations.html), as demonstrated in this table syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE `yourtable` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `city` varchar(28),
  `country` varchar(28),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `city` (`city`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

(table layout based on best guess)

Comment: I already use UTF 8. Hmm... I think the table is set to use UTF8

Comment: Make sure you use `utf8_bin` as collation, too.

Comment: I changed that from utf8_unicode_ci. It works. Gee I wonder why utf8_unicode_ci doesn't?

Comment: great comment. Selected as answer